# Getting Coordinates from Given Lists

Tags: python

I want to get the coordinate of each data represented by row and column positions given by the list (row_cols).

The x_size and y_size of each data are given by the lists(x_sizes and y_sizes).

```
row_cols = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

x_sizes = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
y_sizes = [60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]

for row_col, x_size, y_size in zip(row_cols, x_sizes, y_sizes):
    row, col = row_col[0], row_col[1]

    coord = (row + x_size, col + y_size) ##My trial; I could not imagine further!
    print coord
```

The expected coordinate values are below, and it should be pop out when I print coord

```
(0,0)
(50,0)
(100,0)

(0,60)
(50,60)
(100,60)

(0,120)
(50,120)
(100,120)
```

How can I do it? It has to be done using given 3 lists (row_cols, x_sizes, y_sizes)

As seen in the expected answer, the coordinate for row,col position is increased by the sum of x_size and y_size...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code to produce the answers you say would be like this:

```
row_cols = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

x_sizes = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
y_sizes = [60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]

for row_col, x_size, y_size in zip(row_cols, x_sizes, y_sizes):
    row, col = row_col[0], row_col[1]

    coord = (col * x_size, row * y_size)
    print coord
```

but you may notice that this does not quite match up with the word description you gave for how these values are to be calculated. The resulting 'coordinate' has x-position of column location times x-size and y-position of row location times y-size. A bit confusing.